# What does the ^ ahead of a software version number mean?

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json

I am thinking of updating a package in my app specifically I am updating "@types/react-router-dom": "4.3.1" to "5.0.0" but its in a giant project and I am afraid to break it.

So I was reading over the package.json file and I found the import "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1" with the `^` symbol ahead of the v number. And Im not sure what it means, so I cant be sure it wont be the cause for the app breaking when i update...

Can someone shed some light on this `^` symbol?

Comment: This is semantic versioning used by npm, you can read more about it here, https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning

Answer (score 1):

`^` means *“compatible with”*.  So for example, if you were to run an `npm update` or `npm install`, with a package specified to a version `"^4.3.1"` in your package.json, the latest `4.x.x` version would be installed, and not a `5.x.x` version since that newer version would be potentially incompatible. There are a few special cases:

**^1.2.3**  is >=1.2.3 <2.0.0

**^0.2.3**  is >=0.2.3 <0.3.0   (0.x.x is special)

**^0.0.1**  is =0.0.1   (0.0.x is special)

**^1.2**    is >=1.2.0 <2.0.0   (like ^1.2.0)

**^1**  is >=1.0.0 <2.0.0

When in doubt with a package, I use a semver calculator like https://semver.npmjs.com/